# Asynchronous function in settimeout called before time

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

Well i have this function here that runs on intervals and what it does is, when it runs, it sets 2 settimeout.

Here's the problem, an asynchronous function that should be called after the 2nd time out is called before the 2nd timeout is even triggered. This is my code.

```
    var runner = Interval.run(function() {
    //-212965881
    bot.sendMessage('-212965881', "Drop usernames now").then(function(){
        ready = 1;
        list = {};
        console.log(ready);
        setTimeout(function(){
            return bot.sendMessage('-212965881',"Round has begun. Please start liking now. Leech check will begin in 1 minute");
        }, 10000);
    }).then(function(){
        ready = 0;
        setTimeout(function(){
            return bot.sendMessage('-212965881',"Leech check has begun!");
        }, 15000);
    }).then(function(){
        //This one fires before 15 seconds
        let msg = {chat:{}};
        msg.chat.id = '-212965881';
        return bot.event('/check', msg);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
},  20000);
```

Not sure why this happens. Perhaps im going about it the wrong way.
Can anyone throw some light on this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `setTimeout()` schedules something to run asynchronously later, it doesn't pause execution. Also the return value from any function you pass to `setTimeout()` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the code inside your `then` handlers are creating un-returned asynchronous code, or basically "breaking out" of the Promise chain without notifying the Promise chain of the activities.

You need to wrap your `setTimeout` inside of a Promise constructor and then also make sure you wait for the interior `bot.sendMessage` invocations to finish by resolving them inside your new `Promises`

Change it to use Promise constructors, see [Resolving a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

```
var runner = Interval.run(function() {
    //-212965881
    bot.sendMessage('-212965881', "Drop usernames now").then(function(){
        ready = 1;
        list = {};
        console.log(ready);
        return new Promise((resolve) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(bot.sendMessage('-212965881',"Round has begun. Please start liking now. Leech check will begin in 1 minute"))
            }, 10000);
        });
    }).then(function(){
        ready = 0;
        return new Promise((resolve) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(bot.sendMessage('-212965881',"Leech check has begun!"))
            }, 15000);
        });
    }).then(function(){
        //This one fires before 15 seconds
        let msg = {chat:{}};
        msg.chat.id = '-212965881';
        return bot.event('/check', msg);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
},  20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

because the asynchronous functions you were trying to invoke are returned few seconds later. The three `.then` you wrote works on the first `Promise` repeatly.

your can use `co` module or `ES6 async/await` to control multiple `Promise`.